# How can I get the saved value in the variable table to show on a form?

Tags: forms

I have a form that gets values set in the variable table if any have been submitted. All of the fields work as expected except a radios field, which always shows the default. Here's the relevant code

```
$one = variable_get('one', array());

$form['one']['visibility'] = array(
 '#type' => 'radios',
 '#title' => t('The title'),
 '#options' => array(0 => t('Yes'), 1 => t('No')),
 '#default_value' => (!empty($one['visibility']))
 ? $one['visibility']
 : 1,
);
```

I had thought that keying the options array with strings would solve this but it doesn't. I'm still Googling, but I'm wondering if there's something easy I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to refer to the [Form API docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x#radios) for radios for tips.

Second, it might make things easier to reason about if you do:

```
$one = variable_get('one', array('visibility' => 0));
$is_visible = $one['visibility'];

$form['one']['visibility'] = array(
 '#type' => 'radios',
 '#title' => t('The title'),
 '#options' => array(0 => t('Yes'), 1 => t('No')),
 '#default_value' => $is_visible,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another field of radios in the form that works correctly, the difference is that the keys are strings, so I tried this again in the above code, this time using strings like "yes" and "no" for keys as well as values and it worked. For some reason, using 1 and 2, or "1" and "2" for array keys will not work as expected in this case.